# What is Branch.io Universal Ads

Tags: branch.io

Starting to use Branch.io I found this option to use [Universal Ads](https://dashboard.branch.io/ads/landing), but note really understanding how it really works.

I put ads from google on my website?
I put ads from my product in others website?
I put my own product/app on my website? If is this one, what is the difference between this and [Journeys App Banners](https://dashboard.branch.io/web/journeys/landing)

I've already read the documentation to install, but did not found a properly answer even don't found this question here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branch Universal Ads help you drive results for web and app campaigns.
This means the Branch Ad links can be used on different Advertising networks to measure analytics on different attributes like clicks and installs for campaigns.
To do this:

- Create Ad Links with tracking parameters and deep linking
- Enable Ad Partners to send them preconfigured conversion postbacks
- View ad performance with web and app analytics

Branch is of an attribution platform than ads network platform. You can use Branch to measure analytics for the ads you are running on various ads network. You can docs to learn about this:https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linked-ads/branch-universal-ads/

Journeys Banner is a different Branch product. Converting your mobile web visitors into native app users is one of the most effective acquisition channels available, and Branch's Journeys App Banners platform makes this easy. Journeys Banner is integrated into your webpage where you would require integrating webSDK to run Journeys. You cannot run Journey Banners on any Ads network like Google or Facebook.

Comment: Sorry, I read so many times. But can you give me examples? "Advertising Networks" like other sites? Create Ad Links, but I can create link without Universal Ads. Enable Ad Partners, like Google Ads? or My clients to Ad on my website?

Comment: Check out [this demo video](https://video.branch.io/product-demo-universal-ads). It will give you an overview on why our Universal Ads are valuable and how it can be done in the dashboard.

Comment: @clayjones94 sorry, just saw the answer today (idk why)